# Test Fragment with espresso lib

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso

My app has only one activity and based on many fragments. How I can test this fragment in a right way? Give me an example, please.
Cause I try this test class:

```
    @LargeTest
public class ActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityEx> {
public ActivityTest() {
    super(ActivityEx.class);
}

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
}

public void testTest() {
  //simple example
    assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

}

And in result I've failed due to ClassCastException.

Comment: Could you paste the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Yeah need more info bud. But just some shots in the dark. If your application is also throwing the error i.e. when running it outside of the test (standalone) then the issue might be that you have code like mListener = (OnSomeListener) activity; in the fragment (std pattern) but the activity does not implement  OnSomeListener

Answer (score -1):

Rather do it like this:

```
public class ActivityTest extends android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
{
    public ActivityTest()
    {
        super(ActivityEx.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
    }

    public void testTest() {
        //simple example
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

If you interested I also posted a tutorial on testing fragments  http://www.stevenmarkford.com/testing-fragments-with-android-espresso-basic-example/